# Data not coming to Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

When submitting to Firebase, only photos are sent, without text and database as such.
I do according to the guide, but I don’t understand what is the reason.

The guide probably uses the deprecated `getDownloadUrl()` method, but the photo does not suffer from this. I do not understand the reason for this, since I am still new in this area, please help, I no longer understand what to do. To understand something, look at Maine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Bvc.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private Button mButtonChooseImage;
    private Button mButtonUpload;
    private TextView mTextViewShowUploads;
    private EditText mEditTextFileName;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private Uri mImageUri;

    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_im);
        mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        mTextViewShowUploads = findViewById(R.id.text_view_show);
        mEditTextFileName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_file_name);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

        mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    uploadFile();
                }
            }
        });

        mTextViewShowUploads.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadFile() {
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 500);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Upload

```
public class Upload {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Upload(){
    }

    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {

        this.mName = name;
        this.mImageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.mImageUrl = mImageUrl;
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_choose_im"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_file_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_choose_im"
        android:hint="Enter"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_text_file_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_upload"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Upload" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_upload"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_upload"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Show"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I wrote that data is not sent or displayed in Realtime Database, but images are sent. I need. so that Realtime Database takes the values

Comment: As I see you're only writing the images, `mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);` right?

Comment: As I understand it, everything is correct, but I don't understand why there is no text in the Realtime Database

Comment: Did you already run the code in a debugger? I recommend setting a breakpoint on this line `mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);` and then checking whether it hits that breakpoint **and** whether all the variables then have the value you expect them to have. --- If they do, consider [adding a failure listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to `setValue` to see if that shows what's going on.